# Zeroes of a sextic polynomial and analytical form

Tags: polynomials, roots

Trying to find to find the zeroes of a sextic polynomial to write an analytical form:

$$r^6-r^5-r^4 \cdot C+r^2 \cdot D+E=0$$

actually $r=\frac{x}{b}$ and I want to find an analytical form for $x$ like for a [quartic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Quartic_function&oldid=569041825).

I'm guessing I will need the zeroes here but I'm not sure how to solve it.

C,D and E are real numbers generated by different data points so they change for every iteration which is one of the reason I want to have x on analytical from so that I can plot it against the data that generates C,D and E.

If there is no way to get an analytic solution is there anyway of finding the zeroes by a numerical method like newton's method?

Thank you.

Comment: In general, this is impossible for quintic equations and higher. Do you have any information about C, D, and E?

Comment: Quite a bit of information is known about *which* sextic polynomials have roots (zeros) expressible by radicals in terms of their coefficients.  If you are willing to use "analytic" functions of the coefficients beyond radicals, there are further possibilities.

Comment: Here is a [2005 arXiv paper by Boswell and Glasser on sextic polynomials](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0504001.pdf) solvable by radicals.  There's an unanswered [Question at MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/233537/solving-the-sextic-equation-using-univariate-analytic-functions-and-arithmetic-o) about solving the general sextic polynomial (once put into Bring-Jerrard form) using specific families of "analytic" functions beyond merely taking radicals.  It's kind of fancy stuff for non-professional mathematicians, when we can find roots numerically to arbitrary accuracy.

Comment: To clarify a discussion of numerical methods, what is known about $C,D,E$?  Are they positive? Or real numbers?  Rational numbers?

Answer (score 1):

This is still the general sextic in disguise, so there is ***no*** analytic solution in radicals.

You can use a Tschirnhausen transformation in radicals to simultaneously eliminate the $x^{n-1}$ and $x^{n-3}$ terms of the general $n$th deg equation. The sextic becomes,

$$x^6+an^2x^4+bn^4x^2+cn^5x+dn^6=0\tag1$$

where $n$ is free parameter. Then use the substitution $r = 1/x$ on your sextic to get,

$$Ex^6+Dx^4-Cx^2-x+1=0$$

This is just,

$$x^6+px^4+qx^2+tx-t=0\tag2$$

If you equate the last two terms of $(1)$,

$$cn^5=-dn^6$$

then solve for $n$, you will see that $(1)$ and $(2)$ have the same form, hence your sextic is just the general sextic in disguise, so no solution in radicals.